# Drop-Down PHP list-If selected something add value

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu

I have this code to make the dropdown list:

```
  <?php

        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        ini_set('display_errors', 1);

        $host = ""; 
        $user = "";
        $pwd = "";
        $db = "";

        /* connect to DBd */
        $mysqli = mysqli_connect("$host", "$user", "$pwd", "$db");

        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { echo "Error connecting to DB : " . mysqli_connect_error($mysqli); }

        $query = " SELECT `name` FROM `monitoare` ";
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);

        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($name);
        $stmt->store_result();

        if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) { /* we have results */
            echo"<select name=\"names\"><option value=\"\">Selecteaza monitorul</option>";

            while($stmt->fetch()){
                echo "<option value=\"$name\">$name</option>";
            }

            echo"</select>";
        }
        else
        { echo"[ no data ]"; }
        ?>
```

I want to do a calculator to calculate a sum of values of this names from the database.I want to do the sum with the selected ones.I have two drop-down lists like this

Comment: what have you tried so far ? what is `name` type in DB ? have you checked [MySQL doc Aggregate  Function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) (talking to myself... seems like I've seen this code be4 ^^)

Comment: I am a begginer in programming  and i do this for a Project and i ask for help everywhere i can.Sorry if i disturbed you but i can't find any solution to make this program work.Name is varchar in db

Comment: OK but what do you *exactly* need to do ? You have the select from DB, you need to know how many people have same name and then show it only one time in the select ? Or something else ? It's not clear to me :/ give an example of desired output for instance : what you have and what you need

Comment: I want to make a calculator that makes a sum of values  of the things selected from db.For example:Someone selects Samsung who has a value of 500 in db and Acer who has a value a 700 in db (there are two separated selectors) and i want to show 1200 that means the sum of the two

Comment: I don't get it, it's still unclear to me... here, you can have *only* one possible selector (Samsung **OR** ACER or another one) from the select list, therefore you won't be able to SUM values for different types/things/selectors.